# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can anyone please tell me why I am constantly getting this error in Python 2.7, See below for the marking of error. Thanks in advance!

I have to make a program to calculate the amount of coins per person and figure out their totals

```
TotalPeople = int(raw_input("Enter the number of people "))
Loop = 0
DC2 = 0
DC1 = 0
C50 = 0
C25 = 0 
C10 = 0
C5 = 0 
C2 = 0 
TVC = 0.0
i = 1

while i != TotalPeople:
    DC2[i] = raw_input("How many 2 dollar coins?")     // ERROR for this line
    DC1[i] = raw_input("How many 1 dollar coins?")
    C50[i] = raw_input("How many 50 cent coins?")
    C25[i] = raw_input("How many 25 cent coins?")
    C10[i] = raw_input("How many 10 cent coins?")
    C5[i] = raw_input("How many 5 cent coins?")
    C2[i] = raw_input("How many 2 cent coins?")
    Total =  (DC2[i] *2) + (DC1[i] * 1) + (C50[i] * 0.50) + (C25[i] * 0.25) + (C10[i] * 0.10) + (C5[i] * 0.05) + (C2[i] * 0.02)
    print "The total is " + Total

iw = 1
while iw != TotalPeople:
    TVC = TVC + (DC2[iw] * 2)
    TVC = TVC + (DC1[iw] * 1) 
    TVC = TVC + (C50[iw] * 0.50) 
    TVC = TVC + (C25[iw] * 0.25) 
    TVC = TVC + (C10[iw] * 0.10) 
    TVC = TVC + (C5[iw] *  0.05) 
    TVC = TVC + (C2[iw] * 0.02)

print("The total value is CAD $" + str(TVC) + " for " + str(TotalPeople) +  " people")
```

Comment: line 14, in <module>
    DC2[i] = raw_input("How many 2 dollar coins?")
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Comment: You are treating `DC2`, `DC1` etc. as if they were lists (with the index syntax `[i]`), but they are integers.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared DC as a integer but then in this line:

```
DC2[i] = raw_input("How many 2 dollar coins?")
```

(and all the consecutive lines ahead), you are dealing with it as if it was a suscriptable object. I think that what you want is to get rid of all the index assignment you're doing inside the while loop.

```
DC2 = raw_input("How many 2 dollar coins?") 
DC1 = raw_input("How many 1 dollar coins?")
C50 = raw_input("How many 50 cent coins?")
C25 = raw_input("How many 25 cent coins?")
C10 = raw_input("How many 10 cent coins?")
C5 = raw_input("How many 5 cent coins?")
C2 = raw_input("How many 2 cent coins?")
```

Comment: The thing is I want to make the variable in an array, because say for example there are 3 people and I don't want to create three separate variables for just 2DC. There will be instances where I won't know how many total people there are and I want it to adjust the size of the variable accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`DC2` is an integer. You're trying to assign to it as if it were a `list` (with indexing). That doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a way to assign it as a list?

Comment: @MuhammadAsadIlyas: Declare it as `= []`, and use `.append` instead of subscript assignment?